# apt key management failure any full online solution or key download method

Tags: apt, gpg, apt-key

Using a Debian9 server, behind a proxy, I need to install a docker client.
So to get a key I use the commands:

```
apt-key adv --keyserver http://WHATEVERKEYSERVERITRY --keyserver-options http-proxy="http://proxy.myclientdomain:4128" --recv-keys 7EA0A9C3F273FCD8
Executing: tmpapt-key-gpghome.BO0J96KdNM/gpg.1.sh --keyserver http://WHATEVERKEYSERVERITRY --keyserver-options http-proxy=http://proxy.myclientdomain:4128 --recv-keys 7EA0A9C3F273FCD8
gpg: keyserver receive failed: no key server available
```

I tryied all keyring/MIT/debian etc... keyservers I know (about 5/6) The proxy is not the cause, apt-update , ping to www.google.com & so on ... are just OK.

I think there is another root cause somewhere else... but it is not possible, **really not**, neither to change anything neither get infrastructure information.

So the question is: is there another method to get the key 7EA0A9C3F273FCD8 100% online, generating a file I can then copy/paste?

Comment: “The proxy is not in cause” — I’ve seen quite a few proxies that work fine for downloads etc. but that mess up GPG key retrieval!

Comment: ah ? thanks ... then maybe  it can be in cause.... ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all else fails, you can use

```
curl "https://pgp.surfnet.nl/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x7EA0A9C3F273FCD8"
```

and extract the public key block from the output, for example

```
curl "https://pgp.surfnet.nl/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x7EA0A9C3F273FCD8" |
awk '/^-----BEGIN/ { output = 1 }; output; /^-----END/ { output = 0 }'
```

Comment: this method worked well for me :) thanks again