# Debian Bullseye Docker package cannot be verified; public key is not available

Tags: debian, apt, docker, gpg

I'm following the guide [How To Install and Use Docker on Debian 10](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-debian-10)
to install Docker in Debian bullseye,
but once I run `apt update`, I get this error:

```
GPG error: https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bullseye InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7EA0A9C3F273FCD8The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bullseye InRelease' is not signed.
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/417586/apt-key-management-failure-any-full-online-solution-or-key-download-method ?

Answer (score 3):

this works instead

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg


echo \
  "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
  $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 2):

To complement Marcus' answer:

make sure the permissions are set correctly by the following commands:

```bash
sudo chmod a+rx /etc/apt/keyrings
sudo chmod a+r /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
```

Comment: You helped me a lot! Thank you! Docker should update the docs. Tried hours other stuff...

Answer (score 1):

You can also make sure that the gpg file is readable by all users. Mine was not and changing that permission solved the problem, as stated in official Install guide!

Comment: What GPG file?   What install guide?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Debian repository in your Docker image,
it may be an issue related to GPG (GNU Privacy Guard) signatures. 
It may also be related to the repository's GPU keys
or local keyrings used for signature verification.

Refreshing GPG Keys may resolve the issue:

```shell
apt-get update && apt-get install -y debian-archive-keyring && apt-get clean
```